# a4j:commandButton passing values in callback

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I'm working with JSF 2 and RichFaces. Can I pass some value from bean to oncomplete function in a4j:commandButton? Some counter (int) for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use EL in there. It's evaluated on a per request basis.

```
<a4j:commandButton ... oncomplete="someFunction(#{bean.someIntProperty})" />
```

Note that this feature is specific to RichFaces components. Standard JSF components (and PrimeFaces) will evalute them on a per view build time only.

Comment: I have found a liitle problem that I can't solve for now: when I put in bean.someIntProperty String, I can't pass it to javascript function, but if I put true/false or int it's OK.

Comment: If it returns a string, then you need to quote it like so `someFunction('#{someStringProperty}')`. Otherwise it will be interpreted as a JS variable name. Keep in mind that JSF ultimately generates HTML/JS code and that you need to make sure that you end up with valid HTML/JS syntax. Rightclick page in browser and do *View Source* to see it yourself. The `someFunction(someString)` will obviously only work if there exist a JS variable with name `someString`.

Comment: If I'm writing like this: '#{someStringProperty}' so it will be '#{someStringProperty}' as String and not the value of this.

Comment: Yes. Please note that those singlequotes are not part of JSF/EL, but just of the generated HTML/JS code. Java/JSF/EL doesn't put quotes around strings (that would otherwise end up in ugly looking JSF pages :) )

Comment: So... what should I put instead of singlequotes? I want to get the value and I don't get it with singlequotes.

Comment: I do not understand you anymore. How exactly does that fail for you?

Comment: I'll write it simple. Value of bean.someStringProperty is (for example) "Hello World". if I'll write someFunction('#{someStringProperty}') I'll get in HTML source someFunction('#{someStringProperty}') and if I'll write someFunction(#{someStringProperty}) I'll get someFunction(Hello World). Both not good for me, I need (in source) someFunction('Hello World').

Comment: So the EL expression is not parsed when you use the singlequotes? This is not normal. What EL implementation are you using? Try using `\"` instead of `'`.

Comment: Sorry, what is EL? I have tried `\'`  and `\"` , I get xhtml errors, something like "sign \ must be followed by >". I can copy the exact error tomorrow.

Comment: I did it in another way. I put `#{someStringProperty}` as some hidden input value and then passing it to the function.